# how do i assign constants on sqlite using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

iam new on rails and i have a problem, i want to add entries with value 0 on my db, but only the form values get inserted.

_form.html.erb

```
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :league %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :league %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :color %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :color %>
  </div>
    <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
 def create
    @team = Team.new(team_params)
  end

def team_params
        params.require(:team).permit(:name, :league, :color, points:0,owner:current_user.id)
  end
```

cmd output:
[image: output]

so my question is: How do i add a constant/current user id to my sqlite dbase?

Thx in advance

Comment: Please don't use screen shots for the output. Instead, cut and paste it. It helps when people can easily replicate or reuse that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle setting the current_user in the controller.

```
# in the controller
def create
  attribute = team_params.merge(owner: current_user)
  @team = Team.create(attributes)
  ...
end

private
def team_params
  params.require(:team).permit(:name, :league, :color)
end
```

Whereas ensuring that certain attributes are set (or have default) should be part of the model itself. There are multiple ways to do that: defaults in the database, Gems or this simple before_validation callback:

```
# in the team model
before_validation :normalize_attributes 

private 
def normalize_attributes
  self.points ||= 0
end
```

Comment: i got undefined method `normalize_attributes' :/

Comment: Please double check that the symbol matches the method name.

Comment: i don't know how to thank you mate! unfortunately i don't have enough repo points to up your awnser but iam forever in gratitude

Answer (score 0):

If you're just developing the application and you can wipe the data, and if the information is static,  then you can do it via a migration.

```
class SetDefaultScoreToTeam < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
     change_column :teams, :score, :integer, :default => 0, :null => false
  end
end
```

For current user, then as already suggested a before_validation or before_save

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

before_save :set_creating_user

def set_creating_user
  self.user_id ||= current_user.id
end
```

You can also do it in the controller create action...

```
def create
  @team = Team.new(team_params)
  @team.user_id = current_user.id
  if @team.save
    #  ... set success flash message, redirect to team list, perhaps
  else
    # ... set failure flash message, render the form again
  end
end
```

If you actually have a relationship between team and user, eg...

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then you can just assign the object, and forget about the id's.

```
def create
  @team = Team.new(team_params)
  @team.user = current_user
  #===
end
```